# Angular MAT: Form validation causes "jit_nodeValue_6(...).hasError() is not a function"

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-validation

I'm not sure why I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_6(...).hasError is not a function`

It looks like Angular doesn't like my call to `title.hasError()`. Anyone know why? Thanks!

Here's my HTML template:

```
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm">
    <mat-form-field >        
        <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" name="title" #title>
        <mat-error *ngIf="title.hasError('required')">
                Title is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>         
    </mat-form-field>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: The question mark is typically known as a _safe navigation operator_: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: @Edric both are correct have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want check  `FormControl` for errors then you can consider `FormControlDirective` that takes `FormControl` as `@Input:` 
**Example**

```
  <input name="name" [formControl]="name">
```

else access the `FormControl` as a property of the `formGroup` along with **.?** [`safe-navigation-operator`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) aka elvis operator

```
 detailsForm?.controls?.title?.hasError('required')
```

**Modified Code**

```
<div class="example-container">
    <form [formGroup]="detailsForm">
        <mat-form-field >        
            <input matInput placeholder="title" formControlName="title" name="title" #title>
            <mat-error *ngIf="detailsForm?.controls?.title?.hasError('required')">
                  <p>Required</p>
            </mat-error>         
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    </div>
```

**[`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materror)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ngIf` as following:

```
*ngIf="detailsForm.get('title').hasError('required')"
```

Therefore you must change `ngIf` in your `mat-error` tag as following:

```
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm">
    <mat-form-field >        
        <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" name="title" #title>
        <mat-error *ngIf="detailsForm.get('title').hasError('required')">
                Title is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>         
    </mat-form-field>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ('hasError') in a simpler way by using ngModel

```
<div class="example-container">
    <form [formGroup]="detailsForm">
        <mat-form-field >        
            <input matInput placeholder="title" formControlName="title" ngModel name="title" #title="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="title?.hasError('required')">
                  <p>Required</p>
            </mat-error>         
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    </div>
```